# Como passar a Sintaxe ou Semântica escrita no campo de texto, para uma Textarea

Tags: javascript, html, embed, objetos

Vamos a tal dúvida, isso mesmo é mais uma dúvida doque um raciocínio lógico.

Tenho alguns `input` na página HTML, e esse mesmo repassa seu(s) valor(es) pra `textarea`, ao clicar num botão.

Ótimo, até aqui tudo bem! Desenvolvi conforme descrevi acima.

Mas tenho enfrentado um obstacúlo e tanto.

Ao escrever semântica HTML, junto a sintaxe Javascript. Esses campos de texto, não repassa *sintaxe* pra dentro da `textarea`.

Isto ocorre depois da inclusão do *evento* `onclick()`, dentro do elemento `img`

## Código minificado, para análise:

**Javascript**

```
 function gera(){
 var a = document.all.txt.value;

 document.all.cod.value='<img src="'+a+'" onclick="this.src=''; document.embeds[0].style.display ='block';"/>'
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<p>Video Thumbnail(Image):</p>
<input type="text" id="txt" value="http://"   size="60"/>

<p>Código Fonte:</p>
<textarea id="cod" rows="10" cols="50" style="color:indianred"></textarea>

<hr size=1 color=silver>

<center>
<input type="button" onclick="gera()" value="Gerar Codigo Fonte"/>
</center>
```

Comment: Podes colocar o código que tens aqui ou num jsFiddle?

Comment: Tens de escapar isto: `.display ='block';"/>'`, deve ser `.display =\'block\';"/>'`. Estás a preencher o textarea com o valor do input ou ao contrário? No texto da pergunta parece-me uma coisa no código outra.

Comment: Podes explicar melhor o que queres que esta linha faça `this.src=''; document.embeds[0].style.display ='block';`?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que pude ver, o seu erro foi não ter escapado as aspas simples dentro da sua string. Se você estiver usando exatamente essa sintaxe no projeto, é necessário definir a função gera de outra forma também, que é atribuindo ela a uma variável sem utilizar a palavra reservada var. Se você não atribuir ela a uma variável dessa forma, ela ficará fora do escopo global, e na hora do onclick vai acusar que ela é undefined.

Segue o seu código com as correções citadas acima, no jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/o7x6wdza/1/

Answer (score 0):

Em virtude ao comentário do [Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/129/sergio) logo acima.

Ter escapado as aspas simples de dentro da [string](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadeia_de_caracteres), foi o ponto fundamental para que tudo saísse corretamente na `textarea`.

## Veja:

```js
function gera()
{
var a = document.all.a.value;
var b = document.all.b.value;
var c = document.all.c.value;
var d = document.all.d.value;
var e = document.all.e.value;

document.all.cod.value='<img id="v" src=\"'+b+'\" title="'+a+'" alt="'+a+'" onclick="this.src=\'\'; document.embeds[0].style.display=\'block\';"/><embed nocache="0" type="application/mplayer" width="'+d+'" height="'+e+'" showcontrols="true" autostart="1" src="'+c+'" style="display:none"/><br><span><a href="http://mplayerplug-in.sourceforge.net/" target="_blank"><img src="http://mplayerplug-in.sourceforge.net/plugin-art/mplayerplug-in.gif" border="0"></a></span>';
}

function ver()
{
var obj = document.all.cod.value;
var janela = window.open("","janela","width=500px, height=500px");
janela.document.write("<html>\n<head>\n");
janela.document.write("<title></title>\n");
janela.document.write("</head>\n<body>\n"+obj+"\n");
janela.document.write("</body>\n</html>\n");
}
```

```html
<p>Titulo:</p>

<input type="text" id="a" value=""   size="60"/>

<p>URL Image:</p>
<input type="text" id="b" size="60" value="https://img.youtube.com/vi/XyelvuqYMhA/default.jpg" onblur="if(this.value == '') {this.value = 'https://img.youtube.com/vi/XyelvuqYMhA/default.jpg';}" onfocus="if(this.value == 'https://img.youtube.com/vi/XyelvuqYMhA/default.jpg') {this.value = '';}"/>

<p>URL Video:</p>
<input type="text" id="c" size="60" value="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XyelvuqYMhA" onblur="if(this.value == '') {this.value = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XyelvuqYMhA';}" onfocus="if(this.value == 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XyelvuqYMhA') {this.value = '';}"/>

<p>Largura:</p>
<input type="text" id="d" value="176"   size="5"/>px

<p>Altura:</p>
<input type="text" id="e" value="144" size="5"/>px

<p>Código Embed:</p>
<textarea id="cod" rows="10" cols="50" style="color:indianred"></textarea>

<hr size=1 color=silver>

<center>
<input type="button" onclick="gera()" value="Gerar Codigo Fonte"/>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<input type="button" onclick="ver()" value="Rodar Codigo Fonte"/>
</center>
```

## Explicando cada processo

**1)** Após o preencher os campos é hora de gerar o código `embed` para introduzir no Site/Blog.

Feito isto, será o momento de executar.

**2)** O usuário clica nesta imagem do vídeo, que será então desativada 
 pela sintaxe `this.src=''`.

Dando lugar a *tag* `title` que até então a *tag* `img` continha.

**3)** Logo é recuperado o objeto `embed`, pelo método `document.embeds[0].style.display = 'block'`, que antes estava oculto pela regra `style="display:none"`.

Ja descoberto, é exibido o Vídeo.

---

Em outras palavras, o **mplayer plug-in** fica aguardando silenciosamente pela ação do clique do mouse sobre *thumbnail*, fazendo assim a sua exibição.